# java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()..?

Tags: java, android

Please help me, I ran into a problem and couldn't find a solution

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.barber, PID: 20568
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(DatabaseReference.java:96)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.child(DataSnapshot.java:65)
    at com.example.barber.Adepter.UserAdpter$1.onDataChange(UserAdpter.java:66)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

UserAdapter.java

```
public class UserAdpter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdpter.MYholder> {
 Context mcontext;
FirebaseUser  fb;
public UserAdpter(Context mcontext, List<User> users, boolean isFargement) {
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
    this.users = users;
    IsFargement = isFargement;
}

List<User> users;
boolean IsFargement;


@NonNull
@Override
public MYholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.user_sarcche, parent,false);
   return new UserAdpter.MYholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MYholder holder, int position) {
      fb = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    User user = users.get(position);

    Picasso.get().load(user.getUrl()).into(holder.circleImageView);
    holder.btn_following.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.usernames.setText(user.getName());

    IsFollowers(user.getUid(), holder.btn_following);
}

private void IsFollowers(String uid, Button btn_following) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(fb.getUid()).child("Following");
     reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
             if( snapshot.child(uid).exists()){

                 btn_following.setText("following");

             }
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

         }
     });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

class MYholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public CircleImageView circleImageView;
    public TextView usernames;
    public Button btn_following;

    public MYholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_us);
        usernames =itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        btn_following = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow);
    }
}


}
```

Model User.java

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String location;
private String online;
private String phonenumber;
private String url;
private String uid;


public User(String name, String location, String phonenumber, String url, String uid) {
      this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
   this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    this.url = url;
   this.uid = uid;
    this.online = online;
}

public String getOnline() {
    return online;
}

public void setOnline(String online) {
    this.online = online;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getPhonenumber() {
    return phonenumber;
}

public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public User() {
}

}
```

I have laid out all the details please answer this problem
Please help, I searched and couldn't solve a problem. I understood from this problem that the component in child(uid) is null

I do not understand what is the solution to this problem please help

Answer (score 0):

In `IsFollowers` the call to `fb.getUid()` returns null for some reason.
A quick fix is to surround the calling line in `onBindViewHolder` with a `null` check:

```java
if (null != fb.getUid()) {
    IsFollowers(user.getUid(), holder.btn_following);
}
```

However, I would check other parts of your code why id can be stored as `null`. Usually this is not a desired value for an id.

unrelated: you use `User` but the provided class is `Alluser`. Also you should stick to a consistent naming of your methods (i.e. `isFollowers` with a lower case `i`).